# "Walking to Work" by Frank O'Hara

Tags: poetry, interpretation, frank-o-hara

I'm looking for any insight on the poem "Walking to Work" (1952) by Frank O'Hara. I feel like the meanings are just escaping me, and I can't find any analysis on the Internet to support/challenge my ideas. Here is the poem in full.

> It's going to be the sunny side
> from now
>     on. Get out, all of you.
>
> This is my traffic over the night
> and how
>     should I range my pride
>
> each oceanic morning like a cutter
> if I
>   confuse the dark world is round
> round who
>      in my eyes at morning saves
>
> nothing from nobody? I'm becoming
> the street.
>     Who are you in love with?
> me?
>   Straight against the light I cross.

Comment: The medial line breaks seem to be a visual representation of crossing the street.

Comment: Gareth, I agree. Do you have any ideas for what the middle section of the poem means? From "This is my traffic" until "nothing from nobody"?

Comment: O'Hara gave a hint: "My formal 'stance' is found at the crossroads where what I know and can't get meets what is left of that I know and can bear without hatred". Frank O'Hara. The New American Poetry.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_O%27Hara#cite_ref-11

Comment: As it stands, this question is more like "what do you think about this poem?" and very open-ended. But what are *your* ideas that need to be supported or challenged? Specifying them might give someone a starting point toward an answer.